# Update Of Chart Series Colors Fails When Drilled Into Chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using the drilldown module and a drop down to allow user to change the color theme works as expected when the chart initially loads and the user chooses a different color set from the drop down. The series' colors change and are maintained throughout the drill path. However, if the user drills into a series at any level of drill and then changes the color set it is not applied to the currently visible series. If the user then drills back up to the initial series view the new colors are present. I am using `chart.update()` to affect the color change like so:

```
$.each(Highcharts.charts, function(index, value) {
  var chart = Highcharts.charts[index];
  chart.update({
    colors: themeOption.colors
  });
});
```

You can test this issue on this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4utnsnsb/).

Here is a more real-world [example](https://jsfiddle.net/4utnsnsb/1/) of our data.

How can I get the chart series colors to be updated while already drilled in?

Comment: Maybe instead of updating whole chart update your points with desired colors.

Comment: @stpoa, that seems a bit of a kludge. My concerns are with other formations of this chart - ones where I generate multiple series and have to create my own drilldown code. It seems like `chart.update` should do all of this as it does update the series colors on initial load.

Comment: I don't think it is a bad solution, because if you use chart.update you are pretty much recreating the whole chart, so updating some points doesn't seem to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can update each point with specified color.

```
const colors = {
  'monoBlue': ['rgb(40,97,152)', 'rgb(57,114,169)', 'rgb(65,122,177)', 'rgb(74,131,186)', 'rgb(82,139,194)', 'rgb(90,147,202)', 'rgb(99,156,211)', 'rgb(107,164,219)', 'rgb(116,173,228)', 'rgb(124,181,236)', 'rgb(133,190,245)', 'rgb(141,198,253)', 'rgb(150,207,255)', 'rgb(158,215,255)', 'rgb(167,224,255)', 'rgb(175,232,255)', 'rgb(184,241,255)', 'rgb(192,249,255)', 'rgb(201,255,255)'],
  'monoGreen': ['rgb(60,153,41)', 'rgb(77,170,58)', 'rgb(85,178,66)', 'rgb(94,187,75)', 'rgb(102,195,83)', 'rgb(110,203,91)', 'rgb(119,212,100)', 'rgb(127,220,108)', 'rgb(136,229,117)', 'rgb(144,237,125)', 'rgb(153,246,134)', 'rgb(161,254,142)', 'rgb(170,255,151)', 'rgb(178,255,159)', 'rgb(187,255,168)', 'rgb(195,255,176)', 'rgb(204,255,185)', 'rgb(212,255,193)', 'rgb(221,255,202)'],
  'monoRed': ['rgb(195,44,0)', 'rgb(212,61,2)', 'rgb(220,69,10)', 'rgb(229,78,19)', 'rgb(237,86,27)', 'rgb(245,94,35)', 'rgb(254,103,44)', 'rgb(255,111,52)', 'rgb(255,120,61)', 'rgb(255,128,69)', 'rgb(255,137,78)', 'rgb(255,145,86)', 'rgb(255,154,95)', 'rgb(255,162,103)', 'rgb(255,171,112)', 'rgb(255,179,120)', 'rgb(255,188,129)', 'rgb(255,196,137)', 'rgb(255,205,146)'],
  'multi': ['#1f78b4', '#50B432', '#ff7f00', '#AA4643', '#a6cee3', '#DDDF00', '#64E572', '#fdbf6f', '#ffff99', '#24CBE5', '#6a3d9a', '#cab2d6', '#b15928', '#fb9a99']
}

console.log(colors)

const options = {
    chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
    series: [{
    data: [...Array(5)].map((u, i) => ({ y: Math.random() })),
  }, {
    data: [...Array(5)].map((u, i) => ({y: Math.random(), color: colors['monoGreen'][i]})),
  }]
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options)

// Update your chart colors
setTimeout(() => {
    chart.series[0].data.forEach((p, i) => p.update({color: colors.multi[i]}))
}, 2000)
```

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/rv4cz3cu/

Comment: Well, this not really working as desired with real data. Issue is twofold: 1) I have many points across each series with up to 5 series, 2) it does not "keep" the color if I change it from with-in a drilled method (so if I drill once and change color those points are updated but if I drill up or drill further down the points are still using the color from the initial load.

Comment: It also causes loss of x-axis labels and the label underlining for those elements that are drill-able.